# Div center-aligned on Android but not on iPhone

Tags: android, html, ios, css

My HTML has several inner divs with `display: inline-block` inside an outer div with `text-align: center;`. This is the expected behaviour: in a big screen, some divs will show up side by side (how many depends on the size of each inner div and the outer div) and the set will be center aligned. When the screen width gets narrower the divs will re-position, and in a small smartphone screen we'll have only one div per row, center-aligned.

This is my MCVE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Align center</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: white;
    }
    
    div.container {
      margin: auto;
      max-width: 1000px;
      text-align: center
    }
    
    div.block {
      margin: 4px;
      display: inline-block;
      width: 320px;
      height: 400px;
      background-color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

If you change the size of the window you'll see the divs repositioning (SO snippet is quite small to see this behaviour, but you can click "full page" and resize the window).

**My problem:**

In smartphones there is just 1 div per row, and this is exactly what I want. But my problem is that the div is not center aligned on iPhones, despite being perfectly aligned on Android phones.

Using the code above, this is the result in an Android phone, you can see that the white margins are the same on left and right:

[image]

But now on an iPhone:

[image]

The div is slightly positioned to the right.

What can I do to center-align the divs?

---

*Note 1*: I wrote *Android* and *iPhone* in the question's title because I'm not sure if this problem depends on the OS (Android vs iOs) or on the browser (mobile Chrome vs mobile Safari). I don't think this is a Safari problem, because the divs are OK on iPad and MacBook.

*Note 2*: It may not be an "alignment" problem: on iPhone, it's like the div was not "compressed" to fit the screen.

Comment: seems to be the block is wider than the view port. Yes. Block is 320px in width and has 4px margin.

Comment: Set the width to a % rather than a fixed pixel width

Comment: May be set the block width to 100% and remove margin. Add 4px padding to the container if you really need padding.

Comment: @madhushankarox, the problem is that I need the margins between the divs in the desktop view. And, to make things worse, the divs have a fixed content with a gives size in pixels, % may not be a solution. Right now is everything perfect on desktops, tablets, phones etc... except for iPhone!

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado, you can write media queries for desktops :)

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your head tags,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Remove div.container from your css

Change block css to

```
.block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: green;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
}
```

if you want to show the blocks 3 at a time in 1 row in full screen:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <div class="block"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: The problem is that I loose my margins if I do that. The desktop view has to be exactly the one that you have if you run the snippet and click "full page".

Comment: you mean you don't want the block to take 100% of your screen in desktop mode? in that case you can set the width to your requirement, or if you only want margins.. you can just add margins to the .block class and it should work. or try and change the height to min-height: 100vh; and see if that fits what you are looking for.

Comment: Yep, that's correct: in desktop mode the container have a maximum width of 1000px, and the blocks will show up (3, in that case) with a margin between them.

Comment: @Gerardo Furtado, how about writing media queries for desktops?

Comment: Edited, try that html.